# Find a line intersecting a known line at right angle, given a point

Tags: graphics, geometry

This is basic graphics geometry and/or trig, and I feel dumb for asking it, but I can't remember how this goes. So:

1. I have a line defined by two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).
2. I have a third point (xp, yp) which lies somewhere else.

I want to compute the point (x', y') that lies somewhere along the line in #1, such that, when joined with the point from #2, creates a new perpendicular line to the first line.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all those poor souls looking for a concrete example using vectors... here I build upon Gareth's answer.

You have a vector from p to r (from 0,0 to 50,-50) and another point, q, which is at (50, 0). The right-angle intersection of q and the vector from p to r is { x: 25. y: -25 } and is derived with the following code.

```js
const p = [0, 0];
const r = [50, -50];
const q = [50, 0];
const l = math.add(p, r);
const m = math.dot(math.subtract(q, p), r) / math.dot(r, r);

console.log('intersecting point',  math.multiply(l, m));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.2/math.js"></script>
```

Comment: Moving the checkmark to this late-breaking contribution from Sean, because it is succinct and includes explicit, usable code. Many thanks, Sean.

Answer (score 7):

A useful rule of thumb in this kind of computational geometry is that you should work with vectors as long as you can, switching to Cartesian coordinates only as a last resort. So let's solve this using vector algebra. Suppose your line goes from **p** to **p** + **r**, and the other point is **q**.

Now, any point on the line, including the point you are trying to find (call it **s**), can be expressed as **s** = **p** + λ **r** for a scalar parameter λ.

Now the vector from **q** to **s** must be perpendicular to **r**. Therefore

> (**q** − (**p** + λ **r**)) · **r** = 0

Where · is the [dot product operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). Expand the product:

> (**q** − **p**) · **r** = λ (**r** · **r**)

And divide:

> λ = (**q** − **p**) · **r** / **r** · **r**

When you come to implement it, you need to check whether **r** · **r** = 0, to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening thinking in vectors.

Answer (score 6):

You can find that point by considering first a generic point `(x, y)` along the line from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`:

```
x = x1 + t*(x2 - x1)
y = y1 + t*(y2 - y1)
```

and the computing the (squared) distance from this point from `(xp, yp)`

```
E = (x - xp)**2 + (y - yp)**2
```

that substituting the definition of `x` and `y` gives

```
E = (x1 + t*(x2 - x1) - xp)**2 +
    (y1 + t*(y2 - y1) - yp)**2
```

then to find the minimum of this distance varying `t` we derive `E` with respect to `t`

```
dE/dt = 2*(x1 + t*(x2 - x1) - xp)*(x2 - x1) +
        2*(y1 + t*(y2 - y1) - yp)*(y2 - y1)
```

that after some computation gives

```
dE/dt = 2*((x1 - xp)*(x2 - x1) + (y1 - yp)*(y2 - y1) +
           t*((x2 - x1)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2))
```

looking for when this derivative is zero we get an explicit equation for `t`

```
t = ((xp - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (yp - y1)*(y2 - y1)) /
    ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
```

so the final point can be computed using that value for `t` in the definition of `(x, y)`.

Using vector notation this is exactly the same formula suggested by Gareth...

```
t = <p - p1, p2 - p1> / <p2 - p1, p2 - p1>
```

where the notation `<a, b>` represents the dot product operation `ax*bx + ay*by`.

Note also that the very same formula works in an n-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks for this. Giving you the accepted answer as yours is the only one that takes what I know (cartesian coords) and gives me an actual formula to plug them into. (I like the vector idea but that raises more questions than answers given my geometry memory.)

Comment: It's a heroic effort from @6502, but this answer shows why I have my rule of thumb about vectors!

Comment: @gareth: When faced with a geometric problem I always think in vectors (that's why I upvoted your answer), but I know that most programmers don't feel comfortable with them.

Comment: Can someone please tell me what variable 't' represents?

Comment: @DallasCaley: `t` is the "parameter" of the parametric equation for the line. It's a real number so that when t=0 the point is (x1, y1), when t=1 the point is (x2, y2), t=0.5 the point is the middle point and so on (t<0 is for points "before" (x1, y1) and t>1 for points "after" (x2, y2)).

Comment: what's ** here?

Comment: @NehaK: power... `x**2` is x², the square of x

Answer (score 1):

The answer line is:

```
y=ax+b
where a=(x1-x2)/(y2-y1)
      b=yp-(x1-x2)*xp/(y2-y1)
```

How the result was obtained:

```
1) slope for the original line:   (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

2) slope for the answer: -1/((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) = (x1-x2)/(y2-y1)

3) Plug this into (xp,yp) we can have the result line.
```

Just calculate the answer from the lines after this (this is too long... I am hungry).

Comment: This doesn't work for `y1=y2` (division by zero). Actually one should not use formulas based on "slope" when dealing with true bidimensional problems. The formula `y=mx+q` only works nicely when you're dealing with 1.5-dimensional problems (i.e. with graphs `y=y(x)`).

Comment: @6502 Hmm. Thanks for saving me the bugs in the future because I would not likely to forget it again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/s/yaz1.html)

```js
let x1, x2, y1, y2, slope, xp, yp, m, x, y
x1 = 0
y1 = 0 
x2 = 50
y2 = -50
xp = 50
yp = 0

slope = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)
m = -1 / slope
x = (m * xp - yp - slope * x1 + y1) / (m - slope)
y = m * x - m * xp + yp

console.log('x: ', x, ', y: ', y )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the slope of the line connecting `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`.  You then know the perpendicular line has a slope negative-inverse of that.

To find the y-intercept, use the slope to see how far the line travels in `y` from `x=0` to `x1`.

```
b + (x1 - x0) * m = y1
b + (x1 -  0) * m = y1
b + (x1 * m)      = y1
b = y1 - x1 * m
```

You can then get the formulas for the line between your two points and the line from `(xp, yp)` with the above slope.  For a given x, they have equal y's, so you can solve for that `x`, then plug that into either's formula for the `y`.

```
m = slope_from_1_to_2  = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
n = slopePerpendicular = (-1) / m

b = intercept_for_1_to_2 = y1 - x1 * m
c = intercept_for_p      = yp - xp * n
```

Thus the equations for the lines are of the form
`y = mx + b`

Points 1 and 2:

`y(x) = mx + b`

Point p:

`y(x) = nx + c`

Set their `y`'s equal to find x'

```
mx' + b = nx' + c
(m-n)x' = c - b
     x' = (c - b) / (m - n)
```

And thus use either formula to compute y'

`y' = mx' + b`

Comment: Thanks. In the equation `y(x) = mx + y2` -- why do you use `y2` to stand in for `b`?

Comment: Good point, `b` should be the y-intercept, where the line hits the y-axis.  `y2` is not necessarily so, let me look over my math.

Comment: Using the formula `y = m*x + q` for a true bidimensional problem means look for troubles. You cannot handle vertical lines with this kind of approach; better to use parametric equations `x = x(t), y = y(t)` instead.