# Get a 3rd point along a line

Tags: c#, math, vector, unity-game-engine

I have a line, start Vector2(4,5)  end Vector2(10,10) for example.
I then calculate a point on this line with a specific location on the line (assume 0.4F for now):

```
float x = start.x + location * (end.x - start.x);
float y = start.y + location * (end.y - start.y);
return new Vector2 (x,y);
```

Now i have the location, and i want to place this point at an offset from the line.
So if the line is at a 45Angle, i want to be able to place a point at X offset +90 or -90 degrees from the existing line. Keeping the new location parallel on the existing line though.

Does anyone have any idea about how to do this?
I work in Unity3D if that enables you do do some more Vector2 stuff or not.

Many thanks in advance,
Smiley

Comment: Related: [Find a line intersecting a known line at right angle, given a point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630596/find-a-line-intersecting-a-known-line-at-right-angle-given-a-point).

Comment: The [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ComputingNormalPerpendicularVector.html) has an article on computing normals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a perpendicular vector to the vector joining `start` and `end` using the following x and y components

```
float x2 = -(end.y - start.y);
float y2 =  (end.x - start.x);
```

and create a 2D vector from those. That give you the direction vector which you can scale accordingly and add to points on your line to generate other points in this perpendicular direction.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I have been using Vector2 for X and Y coordinates all day, i totally forgot that you can use them as a direction as well. I created the new vector and normalized it, to then add it to the middle point i already had calculated. This solves the problem!