# Find a line intersecting a known line at right angle, given a point in spherical system

Tags: geometry, geospatial

I want to calculate intersecting of a line [x1, y1], [x2, y2] at right angle for given a point [xp, xy] in **spherical geometry** (the line and the point lays on a sphere - the earth - and are given as latlon).

My question is easy to describe by a picture:

[image]

The formula for 'flat' geometric calculation on a plane you can find here for ex.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630923/2797243

Comment: Take a look at the formulas in [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mathematical correct description is answered below by Pubby.

---

For my case (calculations with tiny distances, maximum a few kilometers) the approximation based on the **Mercator projection** is accurate enough.

A great source with a lot of code-examples you can find here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

Answer (score 3):

You can represent a line that travels around a sphere as a plane; the line is equal to the intersection of the plane and the sphere.

To find the perpendicular line through the point:

1. Find the plane of your first line
2. Project your point onto this plane
3. Calculate a new plane from three points: your original point, the projected point, and the center of the sphere.

The new plane represents the line perpendicular to the first line through the point.

Comment: nice, ty! This seems to be clear. I think a Mercator projection (which I have just stumbled) is the simpler approach. Any objections?

Comment: @TinoRüb Mercator will give you [Rhumb Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_lines). My answer will give you a [Great Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle).

Comment: great - ty again for explanation.